# Elasticsearch boosting on array element

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
    "terms": {
        "array_fileds": ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
    }
}
```

How can i set boost on each element in "array_fileds"?

I want

9 boost on value1

6 boost on value2

3 boost on value3

Do i neet script?

array_fileds's length is not fixed. is variable

Comment: The array is length is not fixed, how do you want it to behave when you have say 10 elements ?

Comment: @Paulo It has to implemented. it would be 1~10 boosting score in each index. Point is the way to boosting array's element